# What is the grammar from 'erkannt worden wäre'

Tags: meaning, verb

I have this phrase from Briefe an einen jungen Dichter and I am a bit confused:

'Nachklingen erkannt worden wäre'.

It seems to be plusquamperfekt konjunktiv ii from a chart I have found but I haven't found any explanations about it with the verb 'worden'. Some explanations about it would help a lot.

The whole sentence starts with:

> Da ist nichts, was nicht verstanden, erfaßt, erfahren und in des Erinnerns zitterndem Nachklingen erkannt worden wäre;[…]

Answer (score 4):

As an auxiliary verb, the past participle is "worden" and as a full verb it is "geworden".

Perhaps this distinction is what confuses you?

---

"werden" as a full verb:

> [er/sie/]Es wäre (toll, anstregend, langweilig, ...) geworden.

"werden" as an auxiliary verb:

> Er[/sie/es] wäre (gesucht, erkannt, bestraft, ...) worden.

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping the words wrong. "Nachklingen" is not a verb in this sentence, but a noun and part of the prepositional clause "in des Erinnerns zitterndem Nachklingen" - "in the remembering's trembling reverberation".

The verb of the sentence is "erkannt worden wäre" - 3. Person Singular Konjunktiv 2 Passiv of "erkennen".

Answer (score -1):

You don't quote a complete sentence.

Yet what you quote is Plusquamperfekt passiv Konjunktiv 2 (irrealis). The present form is 'erkannt werden'. 'Worden' is the Konjunktiv form of 'werden' in past perfect tense.